# Reference contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, contour-integration, line-integrals

I don't feel safe about Contour Integral for complex analysis.
Espacially because of the hypothesis (regularity, Jordan's curve, ...).

I think my complex lesson avoid it !

I would like to study the Contour Integral deeper. Do you know a complex analysis book which is takes time to study curve and contour integral. Or, maybe, a better way is to study some generalisation.

Thanks you for reading me, have a nice day.

EDIT : As I'm talking about Integration, I would like to use Lebesgue please.

Comment: So you want some deeper theory behind the contour integration, am I correct? Including generalizations? But do you already have a good grasp on the concept and complex plane in general, ways of evaluating such integrals, etc?

Comment: Hi !
I had a first class in complex analysis in Paris. So I used it for residu for exemple.

Comment: Alright. Just, in my opinion, it's a hard topic and it's better to start simple and get your hands dirty with a few examples before moving on to the general theory

Comment: I don't agree with you.